# Enter Data Feature In PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

We have a table in PowerBI Model which was created as 'Enter Data' directly into PBIX file and published in Powerbi Service.
in case if there are any data updates that needs to be done in that table, is it possible to update it from app.powerbi.com or one needs to update the data in PBIX within Powerbi desktop and publish the report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For items created by the 'Enter Data' function they will have to be updated in PBI Desktop then uploaded. This may not apply to you if you know this already, but I've seen people delete the Entered Data table and redo it. You can go into the Query Editor and click on the 'source' gear icon and it allows you to update/add/delete data.

[image]

For static tables, that you would like to be able to update in the service, rather than the desktop, you do have the option of creating a Dataflow 'Blank Table'.

[image]

This works as an Entered Data table, but is only in the service. You can connect your desktop report to it, and load it that way, and will save you having to reload the report every time your static data changes

Comment: Hey @Jon, 
Thank you for your inputs :)
Yes, as of now whenever there were data updates we used to update it via transform data itself.

So in case if I have created a Enter data table in PBIX desktop, I would need to update it from desktop only. The better way would be the one suggested by you to create a data flow